How to avoid invoking DR state service instances that are registered with Eureka using load balanced resttemplate
I have a service A and service B, I am using Load balanced rest template in service A to interact with the service B end point. Usually it works perfectly fine as both the services are registered with Eureka and load balanced rest template able find the instance in some order.
Sometimes the instances of service B in DR getting started and they are also getting registered with the Eureka and throwing 503 when the request forwarded to that DR instances.
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

actual service B endpoint invocation.
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
public TestService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}

restTemplate.exchange("https://service-b/api/info/name", HttpMethod.GET, entity, User.class);

Is there a way to exclude DR instances as they always throw 503? Also I can't hardcode those IP addresses because occasionally DR instances become primary and vice versa.
Apologies, as I can't share the entire code snippet. Thanks in advance.
Edit: I am using springboot 2.7xx

Not sure what you mean by DR? To verify instance health before the call you can use health-checks load-balancing https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/reference/spring-cloud-commons/loadbalancer.html#instance-health-check-for-loadbalancer . To restrict to some instances only, you can use subset load-balancing: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/reference/spring-cloud-commons/loadbalancer.html#loadbalancer-subset or zoned load-balancing https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/reference/spring-cloud-commons/loadbalancer.html#zone-based-load-balancing

DR means Disaster recovery site instances.

Ok. please give a try to the approaches I;ve listed above - you should be able to set it up in a way that avoids these instances using those methods

Thanks Olga, your examples and the zone based documentation helped to fix this.
https://github.com/OlgaMaciaszek/spring-cloud-netflix-demo/tree/non-reactive-new-stack

Happy to hear that.
